# Gauss's law and superposition for parallel plates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, gauss-law

> Two large, flat metal plates are separated by a distance that is very
>   small compared to their height and width. The conductors are given
>   equal but opposite uniform surface charge densities +- $\sigma$.
>   Ignore edge effects and use Gauss's law to show that for points far
>   from the edges, the electric field between the plates is $E =
> > \frac{\sigma }{\epsilon_0}$.

I've searched a lot to find a solution to this problem.

http://aerostudents.com/files/physics/solutionsManualPhysics/PSE4_ISM_Ch22.pdf (solution number 24)
[http://www.phys.utk.edu/courses/Spring 2007/Physics231/chapter22.pdf](http://www.phys.utk.edu/courses/Spring%202007/Physics231/chapter22.pdf) (page 21)

In both of these links, the approach to find electrical field between the plates is

1- create a cylindrical gaussian surface

2- put one end of the cylinder to one of the plates where the area is uncharged (uncharged due to attraction between two plates)

3- put other end to be between the plates.

Since the flux will pass through only one end of this cylinder

$$EA = \frac{\sigma A}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$E = \frac{\sigma }{\epsilon_0}$$

My question is, why didn't we do the same thing for the other plate, and then use superposition principle?
Or simply, why didn't we multiply what we found by 2 because of superposition?

Comment: Because this is enough. Doing the same thing for the other plate would give you the same answer. Why would you double it? - I'm not sure what you mean by `because of superposition`.

Comment: @Steeven  *"this is enough"* doesn't seem to be helpful, because this is exactly what the user does not understand - i.e. why is it enough. (I apologize for criticizing.)

Comment: I thought this calculation lacked the contribution of the other plate. Imagine two point charges along the same axis, and you are asked to find electrical field between them. When you enclose one with a gaussian sphere, you find an electrical field. But shouldn't you consider the other point charge?
In this case, we just dealt with one plate, and I questioned that what the other plate is for.

Comment: Notice that they say the electric field outside of the two plates is zero. In other words, they are already considering the effects of two plates. You can draw the same surface for a single plate in which case the electric field on both faces of the cylinder will be equal and opposite, and then use superposition to determine the field everywhere.

Comment: @user2694307  I suggest you to draw the figure with the plates. On this figure, I suggest you to draw the wide cylinder. One of the plane surfaces of the cylinder is inside one of the plates, right? Well, there, inside, there is no field. If it is not clear to you why, then ask it. The other plane surface of the cylinder is between the plates. Well, in the region between the plates you have ***the total field, from both plates***, not only from the plate in which penetrates the cylinder.

Comment: @MonkeysUncle If I calculate electrical field for one plate, as you suggest, I get a "2" in the denominator. Multiplying that with "2" for two plates is giving me the correct answer.
But now I am confused about under what circumstances I should use superposition. If I make use of the superposition, should I ignore the attraction between the plates, and just analyze them one by one?

Comment: @user2694307  look at my comment, the answer is there.

Comment: @user2694307 Yes superposition doesn't care about forces. Imagine a simple case with two charges. To find the E field everywhere, you just use superposition and add the E fields of both charges. It doesn't matter that when both charges are present there's an attractive or repulsive force.

Comment: @Sofia I have just seen your comment. I understand there is no field inside the plate, that is clear. I also deduced what you wrote in bold from the solution of the question. You enclose one plate, but the electrical field will be from both plates as you say. However, how should I know that whether the field includes two plates or not? How am I supposed to catch that?

Comment: @user2694307  if I understand correctly what you ask, then: in the nature, i.e. there between the plates, it's not only that plate A attracts plate B. Also B attracts A, there is full democracy. So, the field in the middle is due to mutual attraction between the plates. You have the superposition guaranteed. This is the situation that the surface of the cylinder finds there. But, I's appreciate if you'd tell me if I understood your question, and if I answered you.

Comment: @MonkeysUncle that has helped for the superposition, thank you.

Comment: @sofia Yes you have understood my question, and been giving me great answers, thank you for that.
But I'm more interested in how gauss's law guarantees that the field between is contributed from both, even though you don't mess with the other plate. Is it because of the renewed charge distribution of the plates?
Imagine just one plate with the same charge distribution. Then I guess I would end up with the same answer. So where is the effect of the negative charged plane in the calculation?

Comment: @user2694307 E=0 inside a conductor takes all E fields of the system into account. For example if you truly just consider an external field, you would find E inside the conductor. But an external field will cause an induced charge on the surface of a conductor. If you calculate the E due solely to the induced charge there is some E inside the conductor. It's only when you add both of these fields together that E=0 for the final configuration.

Comment: @user2694307   again if I understand you, what happens with the plates is as follows: when you bring them sufficiently close to one another, the field from each plate acts on the other plate. So, the charges on the plates arrange themselves, and the process ends when on the internal surface of one plate (the surface that see the other plate) there is an amount of charge, and on the internal surface of the other plate is the same amount of charge, but of opposite sign, and we have Q = CV. The cylinder you draw ***doesn't select only the field from one plate***.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the superposition principle, in general this is more difficult as that requires you to know the charge distribution on all the objects. Note that this is not always as simple as it may seem. E.g. you say "uncharged due to attraction between two plates", but this is not the correct reason, attraction alone would not yield this, it's the inverse square law which is equivalent to Gauss's law that is responsible for this.

In these sorts of problems, you need both the superposition principle and Gauss' law to draw conclusions about the surface charges. So, while you could have used the superposition principle to correctly calculate the electric field between the plates, you could not have concluded that the surface charges reside on the interior sides of both plates without invoking Gauss's law.

Comment: The charge distribution on a very big flat metallic plate is bound to be uniform, and all of it on the surface of the plates. Also, between two infinite plates, the field is uniform and constant, it doesn't depend on the distance from one plate or the other, -dV/dz = const.

Comment: The fact that the interior of a conductor is free from charges is a consequence of only Coulomb's law. Old experiments on the limit of the photon mass made used of that by measuring the electric field inside a cavity of a hollow conductor that was put in a strong electric field. The slightest deviation from Coulomb's law would cause a charge buildup in the interior of the conductor which then would cause an electric field inside the cavity. See e.g. [here](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.26.721)

Comment: The problem of the user is not with the Coulomb law.

Comment: "uncharged due to attraction between two plates" suggests otherwise.